# automate system maintenance

Tags: windows-xp, performance, maintenance

How do I automate system maintenance? 
I'm using tune up utilities 2010, portable spybot, malware bytes, ad-aware, c-cleaner, and avast free antivirus.
I'm using windows xp.
Please tell me, how can I run these tools and leave my computer. And the computer will automatically shutdown when the maintenance is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first obstacle that springs to mind:

MBAM doesn't allow for automatic/unattended removal of infections.

You can run a scheduled update and scan, but removal of detected infections has to be done manually (unless you upgrade to the corporate edition).

You will probably encounter similar problems with ad-aware and portable spybot S&D.

Avast! and Ccleaner should be OK problem to run scheduled. As for Tune Up Utilities 2010, i couldn't tell, sorry.