# automatic shutdown after maintenance

Tags: windows-xp, automation, maintenance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [automate system maintenance](https://superuser.com/questions/102447/automate-system-maintenance)

How do I set the computer to automatically shutdown after a system maintenance(virus scan, drive defrag) is completed

Comment: You've already asked this, better too: http://superuser.com/questions/102447/automate-system-maintenance

Comment: yeah but nobody answered so I rephrased it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Vista or Win 7 you could try using a scheduled task that is triggered by an event log entry.  Assuming that your utilities make event log entries.

You could also use something like [Automate](http://www.networkautomation.com/automate/7/).  Automate can check to see if the process is running, as well as the event logs.  It can also automate the running of the utilities.  That said, it is very expensive.

I think there are other automation tools maybe able to monitor the presence of processes, but I can't recall them now.